# Switch r settings to not have to create directory when saving files into new subfolders

Tags: r, file, directory, subdirectory

I have code to create new files saving graphics into new subfolders like the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

carb_list = unique(mtcars$carb)

  
iterate = function(z){
  
df  = mtcars |> filter(carb == z)

df |> 
  ggplot(aes(x=cyl,y=mpg)) + geom_point()

ggsave(filename = paste0("new/carb",z,"/plot.png"))
  
}

sapply(carb_list, iterate)
```

However, each time this runs, it causes me to have to approve the creation of a new subfolder, as I receive this prompt in the console:

```
Cannot find directory new/carb4.
ℹ Would you like to create a new directory?
```

This used to never be the case, as it would automatically create a new subfolder for me, and not require manual approval. But on the most recent r update [4.3.3 (Angel Food Cake)] it now requires this every time.

Is there a way to configure r so that it never asks, and just automatically creates the subfolders? I say configure because I would like this to always apply on every file/project. I have seen other workarounds where you can tell it to create a folder with a function if not already created, but it appears on an individual basis for each file name/folder. I do not want this, I would instead like the old way where it automatically generates the subfolder, as I have too many different subfolders/files to do this one-by-one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not actually caused by a change in your R version but was introduced in [`ggplot2 3.5.0`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/news/index.html):

> `ggsave()` no longer sometimes creates new directories, which is now controlled by the new `create.dir` argument ([#5489](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/5489)).

You can set this to `TRUE` to recursively create directories:

```r
iterate <- function(z) {
    df <- mtcars |> filter(carb == z)

    df |>
        ggplot(aes(x = cyl, y = mpg)) +
        geom_point()

    ggsave(filename = paste0("new/carb", z, "/plot.png"), create.dir = TRUE)
}
```

#### General approach

More generally, e.g. with other plotting libraries, you can use `dir.create(recursive = TRUE)` to create directories if they do not exist.

```r
iterate <- function(z) {
    df <- mtcars |> filter(carb == z)

    df |>
        ggplot(aes(x = cyl, y = mpg)) +
        geom_point()

    outfile  <- paste0("new/carb",z,"/plot.png")
    outdir  <- dirname(outfile)
    if(!dir.exists(outdir)) dir.create(outdir, recursive = TRUE)
    ggsave(filename = outfile)
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This works perfectly. I didn't realize ```ggplot2``` had been updated!